Make a forecast based on a specific GCP ARIMA_PLUS model
I have used GCP BigQuery CREATE MODEL(...) to create a number of competing models, ranked by AIC.
Is there a way to make a forecast, where I can specify to use e.g. the ARIMA(2,0,0) model?
I.e. the one ranked 4th. Not the one with best AIC.
This is my CREATE MODEL(...).
CREATE MODEL `...dataSetTest001.ArimaPModelOrd2Horiz7_001`
OPTIONS(MODEL_TYPE='ARIMA_PLUS',
         time_series_timestamp_col='date',
         time_series_data_col='Data',
         HORIZON=7, # The number of time points to forecast.
         AUTO_ARIMA_MAX_ORDER = 2,AUTO_ARIMA_MIN_ORDER = 2) AS
SELECT
  date,
  Data
FROM
  `...dataSetTest001_table_ts_demo_csvcsv`

And these are the ARIMA models, ranked by AIC.

